# Assistance with relational tables

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me with this? I'm sure it's easy I'm just missing something.

I need to create 4 tables with this. I've came up with a Customer Table (Cust. Id and Name), Inventory Table ( Item#, Description, MSRP, Price), and a Sales Table(Invoice#,Item#,Quantity).

Could anyone confirm that would be correct and any advice on the fourth table?

[image]

Comment: How can we guess what the fourth table should be?

Comment: Sorry is the picture not working? I attached a picture with the information. It is all in one table and needs to be broken into 4 relational tables.

Comment: Please list the requirements as part of your question, it's quite unclear what you're asking.

Comment: 1. The assignment will require you to create the 4 relational tables that solve the update, insert, and delete anomalies for the table. Do not populate the fields with data. One table will require a concatenated key. My professor didn't give much information.

Comment: What's the difference between `date` and `order date`? Date of what?

Comment: That's the main part that confused me. I'm assuming date invoice was sent out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have customer, inventory, invoice and invoice items table.
Which is basically the 3 you have plus the invoice one. Your sales table will better named as invoice item.
The invoice table should have invoice number, date, order date and customer ID fields at least